# Definitions of a set in the metaverse

Tags: set-theory

In *Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory* by Takeuti & Zaring (1982), the predicate "$y$ is a set" or $\mathsf{set}(y)$ is written $\exists x  ~(y=x)$. However, as I understand from Kunen's *Set Theory* (2013), this cannot be the correct predicate when working in class theory (e.g., $\mathsf{NBG} $), as variables might also be classes. The formula he suggests is $\mathsf{set}(y) =\exists x ~ (y\in x)$.

Roughly speaking, what's the formal definition of a set? More precisely, I am quite confused about how does one treat classes vs. sets in this sense. When evaluating a formula (under some assignment), aren't all variables sent to sets anyway?

Comment: In NGB, a set is a class that is an element of a class. In set theories like ZFC, "set" is undefined. In NGB, variables are quantified over classes, but you can add a clause so that you only consider sets, as being a set is a first order defined notion.

Comment: If we take $``x\textrm{ is a set}"\leftrightarrow\exists x(y\in x)$ as a definition, is the empty set no longer a set?

Comment: @C7X the correct formula in NGB is that $x$ is a set if and only if $\exists y(x\in y)$. Alternatively, your formula defines "$y$ is a set". Note your formula is nonsensical because you are defining $x$ but it appears bounded, and $y$ is a free variable in the entire expression. It's not a well-formed definition.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Then what is the purpose of the definition of a set in Takeuti & Zaring? Also, what is the formal logical frame that allows us to differ variables for classes ($X,Y,Z,...$) and sets ($x,y,z,...$)?

Comment: I am not familiar with that book, so I cannot say about its "purpose". It seems like they just say that the objects of the theory are "sets", and "sets" are the object of the theory. Your second question seems incoherent to me. In NGB there is no "different variables". All variables refer to classes. Sets are classes that satisfy additional properties. Using upper and lower case is just notational convention, not part of the theory.

Comment: In most set theories (eg, ZFj "set" is **not** formally defined: it is a primitive notion with no definition. The axioms just tell us their properties, just like "point" and "line" are undefined in geometry and the axioms just tell us their properties. In theories like NGB, "class" is an undefined notion, and "set" is formally defined as I indicated: a set is a class which is in the relation "is a member of" (another primitive/undefined notion) with another class.